# Query Range in MongoExport?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoimport, mongoexport

I want to know how I can do a range query in MongoExport.

I'm trying in three different ways:

```
mongoexport --host localhost:27017 --db Nsa --collection sat --type=csv --fields Time,latitud,longitud,wind_Speed,wind_dir --query { $and: [ {Time:{$gt:"2015006"}}, {Tiempo: {$lt:"2015008"}}]} --out /home/Desktop/fin/data.csv

mongoexport --host localhost:27017 --db Nsa --collection sat --type=csv --fields Time,latitud,longitud,wind_Speed,wind_dir --query { Time:{"$gt":"2015006","$lt":"2015008"}} --out /home/Desktop/fin/data.csv

mongoexport --host localhost:27017 --db Nsa --collection sat --type=csv --fields Time,latitud,longitud,wind_Speed,wind_dir --query { Time:{$gt:"2015006",$lt:"2015008"}} --out /home/Desktop/fin/data.csv
```

But this give me the following error:

```
too many positional arguments: [$and: [ {Tiempo:{$gt:"2015006"}}, {Tiempo: {$lt:"2015008"}}]}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The query must be given inside single quotes

```
mongoexport --host localhost:27017 --db Nsa --collection sat --type=csv --fields Time,latitud,longitud,wind_Speed,wind_dir --query '{ Time:{$gt:"2015006",$lt:"2015008"}}' --out /home/Desktop/fin/data.csv
```

Comment: this dont work, same problem:
 too many positional arguments: [Time:{$gt:"2015006",$lt:"2015008"}}']

Comment: Can you share the full command that you are running? Also, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me remoting to a docker container with mongo:4.2.6

```
mongoexport -h mongodb:27017 --authenticationDatabase=admin -u username -p password -d database -c collection -q {"created_date": { "$gte": { "$date": "2020-08-03T00:00:00.000Z" }, "$lt": { "$date": "2020-08-09T23:59:59.999Z" } } } --fields=somefield1,somefield2 --type=csv --out=/archive.csv
```